# My laptop shuts down when busy

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome

I am running Windows 7 on my lenovo v460 laptop & while playing games windows shut down automatically.

Sometimes windows does not restart and when I try to restart it, the screen freezes.

What is causing this, and how can I fix it?

Comment: Sounds like overheating, but I think more detail is need. It only shuts down when playing games?

Comment: We need more information. How about safe mode and what event logs says?

Answer (score 3):

I would say without a doubt it's overheating. You need to make sure that the laptop is getting good airflow to and from **all** the vents. So if you're playing on your laptop while it's sitting on a blanket, pillow, or your lap, then you probably want to start looking for solid surface to sit it on.

FYI... The reason it doesn't come back on right after it shuts off is because it's still overheated. That's why it turns back on a few minutes later after it has cooled off some.

Comment: Clear case of overheating i.e above 90 degree. Get cooling pad or make sure the Laptop is on flat surface.